# Display a list of students where both students like each other in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sample database which you can view here: https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/db/asset/socialdata.html

and I am trying to write an sql statement that does the following:*Display a list of students where both students like each other.*

This is my code:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, C.name, D.name
FROM Highschooler A, Highschooler B, Highschooler C, Highschooler D, Likes L
WHERE A.ID = L.ID1 AND B.ID = L.ID2 AND C.ID = L.ID2 AND D.ID = L.ID1 AND A.name < B.name AND D.name < C.name
ORDER BY A.name, B.name, C.name, D.name ASC;
```

I am not sure if it's displaying right this is what I get:

```
Alexis      Kris        Kris        Alexis
Andrew      Cassandra   Cassandra   Andrew
Austin      Jordan      Jordan      Austin
Brittany    Kris        Kris        Brittany
Cassandra   Gabriel     Gabriel     Cassandra
Jessica     Kyle        Kyle        Jessica
```

Comment: Why four instances of Highschooler? A and B is sufficient.

Comment: Well I need to show that both students like each other so A has to like B but B has to also like A. Thats the problem lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that what you are looking for is something like:

```
select A.name || ' likes ' || B.name
from   Highschooler A
join   likes          on A.id = Likes.ID1
join   Highschooler B on B.id = Likes.ID2
```

Comment: This is what I am getting with that:Gabriel likes Cassandra
Cassandra likes Gabriel
Andrew likes Cassandra
Brittany likes Kris 
Alexis likes Kris
Austin likes Jordan
Gabriel likes Alexis
Jessica likes Kyle
John likes Haley
Kyle likes Jessica

Comment: its not quite what I need the first two are correct but the others are not

Comment: You should get a total of 10 results. The same as are in the table likes.

Comment: how can you evaluate that the first two are correct and the others are not?

Comment: well because if Andrew Likes Cassandra then Cassandra should like Andrew at least thats how im interpreting the problem.

Comment: select A.name || ' likes ' || B.name
from   Highschooler A
join   likes          on A.id = Likes.ID1
join   Highschooler B on B.id = Likes.ID2

union all

select A.name || ' likes ' || B.name
from   Highschooler A
join   likes          on A.id = Likes.ID2
join   Highschooler B on B.id = Likes.ID1

Comment: Okay it works lovely only one question can i get the two mutual likes side by side?